# In new appium version(8), as launchApp and closeApp are removed, how do I close and relaunch app in same session now

Tags: android, appium, appium-java

In appium version 8 and above, close and relaunch App methods are removed. What the alternative for these as we have a requirement to close and launch multiple times in our App.

Answer (score 0):

It is for a reason they have removed it, you can instead use following

1. terminateApp - Closing the app, this takes bundleId/ appPackage
2. activateApp - Opening the app, this also takes bundleId/ appPackage